# Adxstudio installer keeps hanging

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals

I've imported adxstudio into my CRM online, when I try to run the installer hangs in the loading stage. What might be the problem?.

Thanks

Comment: Can you look at the network traffic when you hit install - it will start communicating with the Adxstudio installer server. Check to see if there are any network problems (500s, 404s etc.). I've had that before.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this two times, but underneath, the portal was still provisioned.

Two places to check
1. Is the adxstudio solution available in your crm?
2. Does your public site load?

If so, it's provisioned, despite the installer hanging.